# CSS3 Animation Fluctuating after updating Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation

I am using CSS3 Animation of Clouds as a background of my website. After updating Firefox to newer version (Firefox 33) the animations start fluctuation.
Animation is working perfectly on Chrome 38 and earlier versions of Firefox (Before Firefox 33).

Here is a link of CSS3 Cloud Animation

[CSS3 Cloud Animation Link](http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/jEGFA)

```
CSS
```

Comment: Did you clear completely your browser's cache before testing...and did you check if you use hardware acceleration ("Tools->Options->Advanced->General") ?

Comment: @bodi0 'Use Hardware Accel' option is checked.. why remove cache ?? if there is a problem with cache then why its working perfectly on chrome ?? problem appeared after updating firefox to version 33

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue i see, is that you are not using the standard css properties, but only the vendor prefixed ones. (*and the prefixed version is not guaranteed to match the standard one*)

You are also missing some `;` on some properties and that makes that property along with the following one (*if they exist*) to not work.

Try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IkewC
(*i have added the standard properties for `animation`, `transform`, `keyframes` and fixed the missing `;`*)

Comment: Thanx for your response.. I checked your code unfortunately problem still persists. Animation starts fluctuation after 10 to 15 minutes.. I dont know why ?? but it appeared after updating firefox to version 33..

Comment: @Zain with fluctuation you mean some jittering or the fact that when an image restarts its loop it makes a big jump ?